# How to create a git branch of a branch within Rstudio to work on individual functions seperately

Tags: r, git, rstudio

I am pretty new to git but have got as far as getting my development and master branches working fine and merging etc.

I often have separate functions that I work on independently and in parallel so I dont want to merge the development branch (which may have several unfinished functions on it) into the master branch until everything is done.

So the question is: For each function should I create a separate branch that is a branch of the development branch(and how do I do this branch of a branch in RStudio?) or should I simply create a new branch for each function that merges directly into master?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have two questions:

1. "For each function should I create a separate branch that is a branch of the development branch... or should I simply create a new branch for each function that merges directly into master?"
2. "[H]ow do I do this branch of a branch in RStudio?"

The first question is a matter of opinion. There are many git workflows (the ones you are considering are called "gitflow" and "feature branch workflow" respectively). that have been written about variously, for example [here](https://buddy.works/blog/5-types-of-git-workflows). Personally, I use the feature branch workflow, but you should choose whichever works best for you.

Your second question is truly a technical question, and here's how you do it:

#### Creating branches

To create a branch, press the purple-ish button on the git pane that looks like two rectangles connected by lines to a diamond (at least for me it's near the far right):

[image]

I named the new branch "dev":

[image]

I created basically a dummy commit to make the `dev` branch different from the `master` branch:

[image]

#### Branching from another branch

You may have noticed in my git pane screenshot above, the word "master" was right beside the branch button. That means my new branch was created from `master`. If I repeat the process from `dev`:

[image]

I can create `dev1a` **from** the `dev` branch (what you're after -- a "branch of a branch"). I can then create another essentially dummy commit, and examine the log (or "history") so you can see that this is indeed what has happened:

[image]